# How to properly use wp_editor() from frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create a simple form for my wordpress theme's custom page template, but the problem i can not get the toolbar of tinymce editor. I have searched and found some resources but nothing work with me. here is my code

```
            <?php
        $content = 'Start typing to create.';
        $editor_id = 'ic_colmeta_editor';
        $settings =   array(
            'wpautop' => true,
            'media_buttons' => true,
            'textarea_name' => $editor_id, 
            'textarea_rows' =>get_option('default_post_edit_rows', 10), 
            'tabindex' => '',
            'editor_css' => '', 
            'editor_class' => '',
            'teeny' => true,
            'dfw' => true,
            'tinymce' => true,
            'quicktags' => true 
            );
        wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings); ?>
```

and in function.php

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'tinymce_js', includes_url( 'js/tinymce/' ) . 'wp-tinymce.php', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
```

I also tried by removing concatenate scripts by adding in wp-config.php

define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);

But the result is always same as [please view the image](http://prntscr.com/f5dnjc)

The toolbar is missing. So the question is how can i solve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to load your script with a dependency for `tiny_mce`? Something like

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );

function my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js', array( 'jquery', 'tiny_mce' ) );
}
```

Then in `custom_script.js` you should be able to use TinyMCE functionality (you'd place your code in this file).

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: yeah i tried but nothing happen, can you please help me with the js code for TinyMCE functionality

Comment: Try adding a textarea with a class and then in your script use `tinyMCE.init();` to initiate it on that specific class.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, It's as simple as that:

For example turning normal textare into wp_advanced editor does not need any more 3rd party editors or so, just change the normal html code to wp code as follow:

**We need to change:**

`<textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="taxBtmDesc" id="taxBtmDesc"><?php echo esc_attr( $term_btm_desc ) ? esc_attr( $term_btm_desc ) : ''; ?></textarea>`

**To this simple code:**

`<?php wp_editor($term_btm_desc, 'taxBtmDesc'); ?>`

**And the final results will be like this:**

[image]